# Artifacts in loaded texture - Three js

Tags: three.js, 3d, textures

I am trying to render an object with UV maps and updating the texture with a loaded image thru Three JS. My problem is, I'm having artifacts on the rendered result. Why does this happen?

[image]

Notes:

- Object is from a gltf file
- I used blender for creating the model
- I used KhronosGroup's blender gltf exporter for exporting the model
- Image texture is 3239x2745 big

Here's my code

```
var inside_image = load_image("texture/inside.jpg");
var outside_image = load_image("texture/outside.jpg");
var textures      = [];

Promise.all([inside_image, outside_image]).then((images)=>{
    console.log('image', images);
    for (var i in images) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var compositeTexture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
        compositeTexture.wrapS = compositeTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        compositeTexture.repeat.y = -1;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = images[i].width;
        canvas.height = images[i].height;
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,0,0);

        ctx.drawImage(images[i], 0, 0, images[i].width, images[i].height);
        compositeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
        textures.push(compositeTexture);
    }

        loader.load(
        'http://local.webgl.com/model.gltf',
        function ( gltf ) {
            console.log('gltf', gltf);
            gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    if (child.material.name == "Inside") {
                        child.material.map = textures[0];
                    } else {
                        child.material.map = textures[1];
                    }
                console.log('child', child);
                }
            });


            scene.add(gltf.scene);

            // mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
            // animations = gltf.animations;
        },
        // called when loading is in progresses
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {

            console.log( 'An error happened', error );

        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Could you provide a live code example?

Comment: I've just edited the post and added my code. Unfortunately I can't put the code in js fiddle because I need real web hosting for loading the gltf file

Comment: If you drag the file into don McCurdys  gltf web viewer.. do you see the same artifacts?

Comment: @manthrax I don't think everybody knows what Don McCurdy's GLTF viewer is. Here's the link: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ just in case.

Comment: I've already found out what the problem was. The image had an embedded CMYK profile and is very large. I tried loading the image through the browser and it had the same artifacts. To fix the issue I copied the image and pasted it on an image with RGB profile and resized it to 1024 width. Now I'm not getting the artifacts.